# Algorithm to find two subsets of an array which are maximum & equal

Tags: algorithm, subset

The question originally is:

> You have to place an electronic banner of a company as high as it can
>   be, so that whole the city can view the banner standing on top of 2
>   pillars. The height of two pillars are to be chosen from given array..
>   say [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]. We have to maximize the height of the two pillars
>   standing side by side so that the pillars are of equal height and the
>   banner can be placed on top of it. So for this case, maximum height is 8 and the pillar sets will be: [2,6],  [4,3,1]
>
> It is not necessary that all the elements of the array have to be
>   used.  Say, Array = [1,2,3,4,7] then maximum height is 7 and sets are
>   [7], [4,3]

This problem is different from the subset sum problem in Dynamic programming because here all elements need not be part of the solution set.

I am trying to think of an approach to this problem and its extension, *if instead of two pillars we have `n` pillars*.
Which is, how would the approach differ if we had to find `n` subsets of an array which are maximum & equal?